# What do Chazal say as to why Avram and Terach left Ur Kasdeem

Tags: science, abraham, genesis-bereishith

The Torah in Bereishis does not elaborate as to why Terach and Avram left Ur Kasdeem.
Could it have been because of a massive  earthquake and the fear that it might reoccur and harm the family? The present location on Ur is on the seismic (earthquake) belt in Iraq between the Eurasian and Arabian tectonic plates that is known for its intense earthquakes.

Could it have been an earthquake?

Comment: Where in Tanakh are earthquakes mentioned? - [Shemot 19:18, Bamidbar 16:31-32 , Bamidbar 26:10, 1 Melakim 19:12].